# Library messenger like slack

Tags: angular, html-parsing, messenger

I work with angular4 and need to implement messenger like [Slack](http://www.slack.com/%E2%80%8E).

To be able to add **emoji**,

[image]

add **@Users**

[image]

and if type **url** - show it like **link**.

**Could you advise a library or how to create such component?**